# Android ndk undefined reference using crypto++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stdstring

So i have build a static Libary of Crypto++ for Android.
I want to build my own libary now and use the crypto++ libary.
For the Build I use this Android mk:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := StaticLibrary3.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := crypt
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcryptopp.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Now when i link the libary into the project, i get a lot of errors about undefined referneces like this:

```
string.c:600: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)
```

or

```
alloc.h:158: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: _"What have i done wrong?"_ - You didn't include the error messages in your post.

Comment: Try adding LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSTDC_HEADERS

Answer (score 0):

Your Application.mk must define APP_STL that fits the STL settings used for the prebuilt cryptopp library.